# generate resources from an AutoPlugin in sbt

Tags: sbt, sbt-plugin

I have created the following plugin, like so many plugins before it...

```
/**
 * This plugin automatically generates a version number based on the configured
 * minor version and today's date and time.
 */
object DateVersionPlugin extends AutoPlugin {
  //override def trigger = allRequirements

  def dateFormat (fmt : String) =
    new java.text.SimpleDateFormat(fmt).format(
      new java.util.Date()
    )

  def versionNumber (majorVersion      : String,
                     versionTrimFront  : Int,
                     versionDateFormat : String) =
    "%s.%s".format(
      majorVersion, dateFormat(versionDateFormat).substring(versionTrimFront)
    )


  /**
   * Defines all settings/tasks that get automatically imported,
   * when the plugin is enabled
   */
  object autoImport {
    /**
     * The number of values to trim off the front of the date string.
     *
     * This is used to achieve a date string which doesn't include the
     * present millenium.  The century, a stretch, can be imagined as
     * conceivable - but few civilizations have lasted multiple millennia.
     */
    lazy val versionTrimFront    = settingKey[Int]("Number of characters to remove from front of date")

    /**
     * The format to use for generating the date-part of this version number.
     */
    lazy val versionDateFormat   = settingKey[String]("The date format to use for versions")

    /**
     * The major version to place at the front of the version number.
     */
    lazy val versionMajor        = settingKey[String]("The major version number, default 0")

    /**
     * The filename of the generated resource.
     */
    lazy val versionFilename     = settingKey[String]("The filename of the file to generate")

    /**
     * The name of the property to place in the version number.
     */
    lazy val versionPropertyName = settingKey[String]("The name of the property to store as version")

    /**
     * Generate a version.conf configuration file.
     *
     * This task generates a configuration file of the name specified in the
     * settings key.
     */
    lazy val generateVersionConf = taskKey[Seq[File]]("Generates a version.conf file.")
  }

  import autoImport._

  /**
   * Provide default settings
   */
  override def projectSettings: Seq[Setting[_]] = Seq(
    versionFilename     := "version.conf",
    versionPropertyName := "version",
    versionDateFormat   := "YY.D.HHmmss",
    versionTrimFront    := 0,
    versionMajor        := "0",

    (version in Global) := versionNumber(versionMajor.value,
      versionTrimFront.value, versionDateFormat.value),

    generateVersionConf <<=
      (resourceManaged in Compile, version, versionFilename, versionPropertyName, streams) map {
        (dir, v, filename, propertyName, s) =>
          val file = dir / filename

          val contents = propertyName + " = \"" + v.split("-").head + "\""

          s.log.info("Writing " + contents + " to " + file)

          IO.write(file, contents)

          Seq(file)
      },

    resourceGenerators in Compile += generateVersionConf.taskValue
  )
}
```

The `generate-version-conf` task behaves as desired, generating the file I'm looking for.  The `version` setting is updated as expected by projects that use this plugin.  But yet the following are *not* happening and I'm not clear why:

1. The config file is not generated by `compile`.
2. The config file is not packaged in the jar by `package`.
3. The config file is not in the classpath when the `run` task is used.

Note I have also tried a dozen or so variations on this, and I have further tried:

```
  resourceGenerators in Compile <+= generateVersionConf
```

Which as I understand it should result in more or less the same behavior.

Inspecting the runtime attributes of this, I see some of the settings are applied successfully:

```
> inspect version
[info] Setting: java.lang.String = 0.15.338.160117
[info] Description:
[info]  The version/revision of the current module.
[info] Provided by:
[info]  */*:version
[info] Defined at:
[info]  (com.quantcast.sbt.version.DateVersionPlugin) DateVersionPlugin.scala:101
[info] Reverse dependencies:
[info]  *:isSnapshot
[info]  *:generateVersionConf
[info]  *:projectId
[info] Delegates:
[info]  *:version
[info]  {.}/*:version
[info]  */*:version
[info] Related:
[info]  */*:version
```

However, this is not true for `compile:resourceGenerators`, which shows that it still maintains the defaults.

```
> inspect compile:resourceGenerators
[info] Setting: scala.collection.Seq[sbt.Task[scala.collection.Seq[java.io.File]]] = List(Task(_))
[info] Description:
[info]  List of tasks that generate resources.
[info] Provided by:
[info]  {file:/home/scott/code/quantcast/play/sbt-date-version/sbt-test/}root/compile:resourceGenerators
[info] Defined at:
[info]  (sbt.Defaults) Defaults.scala:207
[info]  (sbt.Defaults) Defaults.scala:208
[info] Dependencies:
[info]  compile:discoveredSbtPlugins
[info]  compile:resourceManaged
[info] Reverse dependencies:
[info]  compile:managedResources
[info] Delegates:
[info]  compile:resourceGenerators
[info]  *:resourceGenerators
[info]  {.}/compile:resourceGenerators
[info]  {.}/*:resourceGenerators
[info]  */compile:resourceGenerators
[info]  */*:resourceGenerators
[info] Related:
[info]  test:resourceGenerators
```

My question is (now that I've continued to research this more), what could be keeping my changes to (generateResources in Compile) from being applied?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this plugin needs to require the JvmPlugin.  This is because the JvmPlugin defines the setting dependencies.  Without it, apparently the `compile:resourceGenerators` setting is being overwritten by the defaults, redefining the set of resource generators to `Nil` and building from there.

So the solution is to include the following line in the `AutoPlugin` definition.

```
  override def requires = plugins.JvmPlugin
```